# How can I proof that all $\mu^*$ measurable set is a $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure, measurable-sets

Hi according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) a $\mu^*$ measurable set satisfy $\forall A\subset X\rightarrow\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A\cap S)+\mu^*(A\setminus S)$

I would like to prove that all set that is $\mu^*$ measurable is a $\sigma$ algebra of $X$

More specifically, I would like to prove if $S_1,S_2$ is $\mu^*$ measurable sets of $X$ then $\forall A\subset X\rightarrow\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A\cap (S_1\cup S_2))+\mu^*(A/(S_1\cup S_2))$

Can anyone help me on that..... Thanks a lot

Comment: Standard text book material.

Comment: @kaviramamurty my text book doesn't prove it. Can I have a more specific link or name of the text book??

Comment: Look for Caratheodory's theorem, I will provide a proof as an answer in a bit.

Comment: @varpi thank you very very much!!!